# omitNull not working on primaryKey column in Sequelize

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a SQL server database with a table which auto inserts a guid in each row when a record is added. This column is the primary key for the table and never needs a value to be supplied to it as it's automatic.

The trouble is that Sequelize is sending NULL for this column every time I do a .create({emailAddress:"test@test.com"}) call which is causing an error in the database (because nulls aren't allowed, obviously).

I've tried adding omitNull at the top level and at the "call" level and neither of them work , unless I remove the primary key and then it doesn't send a NULL. So it seems that Sequelize thinks that if something is the primary key then it must send a value, not understanding that the SQL SERVER database is going to handle insertion of that value.

Anybody know a workaround?

// Model

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

    const Player = sequelize.define('Player', {
        playerId: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        emailAddress: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING 
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    });

    return Player;

};
```

// Create a row

```
let newPlayer = {
    emailAddress:'test@test.com'
}

Player.create(newPlayer, {omitNull:true}).then(function(player){
    console.log("player", player)
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("error", error)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `defaultValue` and `allowNull` should do the job

```
playerId: {
  primaryKey: true,
  defaultValue: '',
  allowNull: false,
}
```

Comment: OK, so that will send an empty string, which will be replaced with the GUID in the database which will work perfectly as a workaround. It still seems strange that there isn't a way to get it to send nothing at all but that's just me beign picky. Many thanks.